# What will be the output and why?

Tags: java

```
int i=1;
int j=10;
if(i++ > --j)
{
     System.out.print("i= " + i + "     j= " + j);
}
```

*question asked by* **interviewer**
What will be the output and why?

I have tried this question and found that it will be not giving any output because **if condition will become false**.

*I'm unable to understand this situation, please anyone will explain?*

Comment: `a++` means take the value of `a` and then add one to it, `--a` means subtract one from a and then take the value. The `if` statement you have is saying `if 1 is more than 9` which is false. After the if statement, i will be 2 and j will be 9.

Comment: This question would make much more sense with `int i = 1; int j = 2;`!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I agree wholly. But I imagine the interviewer threw in the `postfix` and `prefix` operators to throw OP off and see if OP would still get the answer when presented with an unusual problem.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Well ... might be. But it does not make sense to use `1` and `10` as the borders because then it becomes unimportant to what value the increment operators evaluate. _You then can answer that question without understanding post- or pre-increment._ The values 1 or 2 are both less than 9 or 10. It becomes interesting, though, when having two consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Unless the interviewer follows by asking 'Why?'. If you respond 'Because 2 is less than 9.', the interviewer has learned something about you.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes you are right. I would make more sense to use `1` and `2`. This way you would have to evaluate the `postfix` and `prefix` operators to determine instead of simply just looking at the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct it will not print out anything as the if statement will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

It won't give any output as in if condition i will be 1 (as post increment operator) and j will be 9 (as pre decrement operator) so in that case the 1 > 9 becomes false.

Comment: If you change it to  if(i++ < --j) it will print i= 2 j= 9. It will compare 1<9 and the as i has postfix operator it will increment after comparison. So i will be 2.